# Minecraft not working in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - Black screen?

Tags: 64-bit, java, minecraft, jdk

This is what I've done exactly.

> I downloaded Minecraft for Linux from minecraft.net
>   I tried running the file using both OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime and Oracle Java 7 Runtime
>   The file opened fine both times and I logged in as so
>   Then the screen went black and stayed that way.

I don't know what to do?

Comment: Could you show the terminal output when running minecraft?

Answer (score 0):

For some wierd reason, i had the same problem until i installed the previous version of java, OpenJDK-java-6-runtime. Try to do that, and minecraft will run pretty well for you too.

use: (in terminal)

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk`
to install it, and then rightclick the minecraft file, and select `run with Java 6`

Good luck!

Comment: I fixed it now. Apparently I was using an older version of lwjgl (2.8.3). I went to www.lwjgl.org and downloaded the latest version (2.8.5). After that I replaced the old files with the new files and now it works. Thanks anyways.